# Open view controller with same tab from tabbed app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a tabbed app , In storyboard I have 4 screens 
Changing from one tab to another it works .
I have for example on tab 2 a collection view .
I want on item click to open a View controller for witch I ve made separate file (there are many screens and i chose for detail views to do separate xibs )
I ve tried with self.navigationcontroller pushvc but it does not open a new page , the view does not change.

Comment: Please explain "it doesn't work" in good detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "it doest not open a new page"? Do you mean you want a view controller presented modally?

Comment: That edit does not add any extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the viewController in tab 2 (the viewController that holds the collectionView) embedded in a UINavigationController ?

If not, `self.navigationController` will return nil.

To embed a viewController in a navigation context, choose Editor > Embed in > NavigationController when the viewController is selected in IB

Comment: no, it is not , and in embedded in all options are unselected and disabled

Comment: you have to make sure the viewController is selected, not the view. The 'embed in' menu will have the two options available when you have selected the viewController for sure! tip: hold (ctrl + shift) and click somewhere inside the viewController. it will give you a context-menu where you can choose from all underlying views

Answer (score 0):

You need to embedded UINavigationCtrl or need to add as subview with transition to achieve this feature.